# python/kivy : access attribute value in .kv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

When I click on Account(root.display_account()) then call display_account().After that RVACCOUNT() function call .After that when i click on +Add Account then def add_account(self): call

I have a class AccountPopup which define a attribute state_text and assign value text:'Testing' in .kv file
How to get value of state_text 'Testing' and pass in on_text: root.filter(self.text,state_text) and print in def filter function.

## test.py

```
class AccountPopup(Popup):
    state_text = ObjectProperty(None)
    popupAccountCity = ObjectProperty(None)


    def display_cities_treeview_account(self, instance):
        if len(instance.text) > 0:
            #if self.popupAccountCity is None:
            self.popupAccountCity = TreeviewCityAccount(self.state_text.text)
            self.popupAccountCity.filter(instance.text,self.state_text.text)
        self.popupAccountCity.open()


class TreeviewCityAccount(Popup):
    state_text = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self,state_text, **kwargs):
        print(state_text)

    def filter(self, f,state):
        print(state)


class RVACCOUNT(BoxLayout):
    def add_account(self):
        self.mode = "Add"
        popup = AccountPopup(self)
        popup.open()

class MainMenu(BoxLayout):

    def display_account(self):
        self.dropdown.dismiss()
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.rvaccount = RVACCOUNT()
        self.content_area.add_widget(self.rvaccount)


class FactApp(App):
    title = "Test"

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return MainMenu()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    FactApp().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<AccountPopup>:
    state_text:state_text

        TextInput:
            id:state_text
            text:'Testing'

<TreeviewCityAccount>:

    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"

        TextInput:
            id: treeview
            size_hint_y: .1
            on_text: root.filter(self.text,state_text)

<RVACCOUNT>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            size_hint: .07, .03
            text: "+Add Account"
            on_press: root.add_account()


<MainMenu>:
    content_area: content_area
    dropdown: dropdown

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        #spacing : 10

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            MenuButton:
                    id: btn
                    text: 'Master'
                    size : (60,30)
                    on_release: dropdown.open(self)

            CustDrop:

                DropdownButton:
                    text: 'Account'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '32dp'
                    on_release: root.display_account()
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Where do you open the AccountPopup?

Answer (score 1):

You should reference it as `self.state_text` everywhere, also make it a `StringProperty` in the py file and can than access it as

```
on_text: root.filter(self.text,root.state_text)
```

root in kv refers to the most left widget aka `<TreeviewCityAccount>:` in your case.

See https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html
[image]

Alternatively you can work with ids in the kv file.

Answer (score 1):

the value you are looking for is not in your immediate root which is why this is not working.The say thing to do is get the full path to that property like so:
**Snippet**:

```
<AccountPopup>:
    id: ac_popup
    #bunch of code
 <TreeviewCityAccount>:
    #chunk of code
    TextInput:
       id: tree view
       on_text:root.filter(self.text,app.ac_popup.state_text
```

Also,generally,it's a good idea to id your classes mate

Disclaimer:code not tested